# Ruby style before() and after() filters for Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add before and after to function calls in Javascript? I have something like this:

```
var A = {

  a1: function () {

  },
};

var B = {

  b1: function () {

  }
};

A.a1();
B.b1();
//so on ..
```

I need something to happen before and after each of these methods. I can just make those before and after functions and call them respectively, but I have to do this often in the code and don't want to repeat myself.

Update:
In ruby

```
before_filter :some_function
after_filter  :some_other_function
```

will execute some_function before each function call in that class and some_other_function after each function call. Also this is not found in Application Controller in Rails.

Comment: Slap a function called `before` and `after` in each object, call `before` in the first line of your function, and `after` at the end?

Comment: You would probably get more help if you would explain what the `before` and `after` functions do in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to change all functions in an object:

```
var beforeAll = function(o, f) {
  for (var p in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof(o[p]) === "function") {
      o[p] = (function(oldF) { 
        return function() {
          f.apply(this, arguments);
          return oldF.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      }(o[p]));
    }
  }
};

var A = {
  func1: function() {console.log('func1')},
  func2: function() {console.log('func2')}
};

beforeAll(A, function() {console.log('before')});

A.func1();
A.func2();
```

(You can create a similar one for `afterAll`).

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLwV2/).

Note that you need to *capture* the old function in the loop to bind it correctly. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem).

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that enumerates the fields of an object and wraps its functions in new ones:

```
function addBefore(obj, func) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] === 'function') {
            (function () {
                var oldFunc = obj[prop];
                obj[prop] = function () {
                    func.apply(obj, arguments);
                    return oldFunc.apply(obj, arguments);               
                }
            }());
        }
    }
}
var A = {

  a1: function (a, b) {
    alert('A.a1');
    return a + b;
  },
  a2: function (a, b) {
    alert('A.a2');
    return a + b;
  }
};
addBefore(A, function (a, b) {
    alert('before ' + a + ', ' + b);
});
A.a1(1, 2);
A.a2(3, 4);
```

In similar way you can write a function addAfter, just switch the two calls to the apply() function.

Comment: I know I accepted this reply but I ran into a complication with this. when A has two methods or more methods then the old function reference always returns the last function in the object instead of the corresponding function. See the update I made to @Jordão 's fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/LTCpj/3/ . Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

if you save the orginal function and call it after(or before) like:

```
var A = {

  a1: function () {

  }
};

var orginal = A.a1
A.a1 = function(){
  // the before code
  orginal.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

*for all props*

```
for(prop in A){
  var orginal = prop
  A[prop] = function(){
    //before code
    orginal.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
```

i leave type checking as an exorcise for the reader :)

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all functions in an object? So something like `for(keys in A){ if(typeof key == function) {//save the original and define a new one} }`

Comment: You should check if the property is a function and use apply as in the first snippet. And be aware of the "this" value :)

Comment: that where suppose to be `apply` not `call`. i leave type checking as an exorcise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the convention is to use callbacks for this sort of thing. So if you wanted to fire one function only after another, it would look something like this:

```
var a1 = function(callback){
  console.log('doing function things la la');
  callback();
}
```

Now, when you call the `a1` function, you'd do something like this:

```
a1(function(){
  console.log('this is only printed at the end!');
});
```

You could, I suppose, add another second param to the function which would be more of a callbefore I guess, but you don't see this very often.

If you're talking about getting a certain function to run before a large number of methods that do not have a callback, I think the best way would just be to wrap them with a function that accepts your main functions as a callback, something like this:

```
var a1 = function(){ console.log('a1'); }
var a2 = function(){ console.log('a2'); }
var a3 = function(){ console.log('a3'); }
var a4 = function(){ console.log('a4'); } 

var before_filter = function(callback){
  console.log('doing some stuff before whoo!');
  callback();
}

[a1, a2, a3, a4].map(function(fn){
  before_filter(fn);
});
```

Let me know if this wasn't what you were after and I'd be happy to add more options -- there are many potential ways to handle this problem, it just depends on what exactly you're looking for. It will be tough to make this as clean as ruby since `before_filter`s are not built into javascript natively, but looking at the last example there, you can see that it would be easy to get it pretty close. One more alternative similar to the last one:

```
var a1 = function(){ console.log('a1'); }
var a2 = function(){ console.log('a2'); }
var a3 = function(){ console.log('a3'); }
var a4 = function(){ console.log('a4'); } 
var before = function(){ console.log('doing before stuff'); }

var before_filter = function(before_fn, fn){
  before_fn();
  fn();
}

[a1, a2, a3, a4].map(function(fn){
  before_filter(before, fn);
});
```